# Rails mass assignment and Backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have a Game model and I want to mass assign on create:

```
def create
game = Game.new(params[:game])
...
end
```

But Backbone sends model attributes without wrapping them in 'game' param, and I have to do this:

```
def create
game = Game.new(:title=>params[:title], ... )
...
end
```

I want my controller clean, how to use mass assignment with Backbone.js?

Comment: For security reasons, your rails controller should only accept those fields that it expects. What if someone sends a JSON object attribute that doesn't exist?

Comment: I have solved this issue with monkey patching toJSON() during sync() call only. Check my solution implemented in CoffeeScript here: https://gist.github.com/1128000

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer From Backbone creator:
http://www.quora.com/How-well-does-backbone-js-work-with-rails

Answer (score 1):

This might help you from what I understand: https://gist.github.com/719080 
(Not my code, gist by @trydionel).