# Backbone.js and Rails - How to handle params from Backbone models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

In a standard Rails controller, I'd create a record like this:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

This assumes that the form parameters that come in are nested.

I've been playing with Backbone.js and I noticed that by default, Backbone doesn't nest the parameters the way a normal Rails form might, which is actually something I expected. So I'm wondering what I should do...

Do I

figure out on the server-side if it's a request from Backbone by looking at accepts headers, etc and manipulate the params myself so I can keep my controller code small:

```
do_some_params_manipulation_with(params)
@user = User.new(params[:user])
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html {redirect_to users_url}
    format.json {render :json => @user.to_json }
  end
end
```

Or, do I instantiate the object in each branch which ends up with repeated code but might be more maintainable in the long run....

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html do
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to users_url
    end
  end

  format.json do
    @user = User.new(params) # and rely on mass-assignment protection
    if @user.save
      render :json => @user.to_json
    end
  end

end
```

or do I modify my Backbone.js models by overriding the .toJSON method (which I'm not entirely sure how to do because I don't know enough about Backbone.js yet) so that it nests the params?

In this situation, I have access to both sides of the app, but I am interested in what others are doing.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's nice when you can have the general Rails forms and Backbone forms match with respect to the root node. That's why in my last application I chose to override the Backbone models' toJSON method.

You could override the global toJSON method [as Raimonds Simanovskis suggested](http://twitter.com/#!/rsim/status/78220812519350274). But even the non-DRY way approach isn't so bad. Just one line of boilerplate for each model definition:

```
// Depends on Underscore.js
User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  toJSON: function() {
    return { user: _.clone( this.attributes ) }
  },
  // Your other methods here
});
```

**Edit:** Corrected code sample. Sorry for the errors, I was translating from CoffeeScript to JavaScript.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it's pretty much on the money, but I decided to just handle this on the server side.

Comment: `this.constructor.name.toLowerCase()` can be used as the object key on a parent Model object `App.Model` which extends `Backbone.Model`.

Comment: This breaks being able to use toJSON in templates. This is no good.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the `backbone-rails` gem, looks like you can do

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
   paramRoot: 'user'
});
```

Around line 45 on [github](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/backbone_rails_sync.js)

Credit PL J and stream 7 on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016296/backbone-model-save)

Comment: awesome!  never knew it included that.

Answer (score 4):

I have made a little hack to namespace save requests under model.name property.
It monkey patches `toJSON()` during `sync()` call only and restores original method so you can use it as usual.

I have implemented it in CoffeeScript.

[Check it here](https://gist.github.com/1128000)

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted that if you opt for the currently accepted answer (patching toJSON at the model level) you are affecting reading as well. Maybe that goes without saying, maybe not. But you will have a lot of work to do when rendering models/collections if you put this patch into affect in a backbone app. Therefore, I personally wouldn't use it as-is.

Answer (score 1):

In one of the answers to [Rails mass assignment and Backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773733/rails-mass-assignment-and-backbone-js) there is mentioned patch https://gist.github.com/719080 which I think will do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As of Rails 3.1 there's now a new initializer called `wrap_parameters.rb` which handles this problem by default.  The code that handle this case is:

```
# Disable root element in JSON by default.
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  self.include_root_in_json = false
end
```

Bada bing!

Comment: This poses as a security risk when returning a list of items.  Root node should always be included to protect against this.  http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/24/json-hijacking.aspx

Comment: Most definitely worth reading.  Some good points at the end of the thread in the link.  In the Rails environment, there's some built-in checking to prevent the cases in which this exploit could be used ... which is not to say it's right to lop off the root node.