# Backbone model save

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm using rails and learning Backbone.

Help me please. Is there any way to set right model on save? When I create, for example, new user with some params and trying save it into the database, - on server side I have not user as object, but user fields in params. And only way to save user - is to set properties manually:

```
user = User.new(:login => params[:login], :password => params[:password]).save!
```

Is there any way which will generate real user model object (like a form_for generates)?
I think actions described below I will need to use when I will update user and so on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a paramRoot 'parameter'. You say rails - so I'll assume coffee script:

```
class User extends Backbone.Model
  paramRoot: 'user'
<url or some other stuff>
```

Comment: Where can I find documentation for 'paramRoot' ?
I am trying to understand Backbone + Rails, but I can't any info on that. Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianoFerrari The actual source code call is here, https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/backbone_rails_sync.js#L44

Answer (score 10):

The 'paramRoot' parameter is used by the backbone_rails_sync adapter that backbone-rails gem provides. That's why you can't find it in backbone's website.

Another way, if you are not using the gem and it's adapter, is to render the user with :root => false

```
render json: @user, root: false
```

Comment: this is EXACTLY what I needed. but I would have never known since their github documentation makes no mention of this. 

Thank you my good sir. :)