# Backbone.js: What is paramRoot: attribute in backbone.model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, backbone-rails

I use rails-backbone gem and I generated a Backbone model. The model includes `paramRoot:` attribute. I assume it somehow tells Backbone how to connect to the corresponding Rails model, but I can't find any documentation about it.

What does `paramRoot` actually do?

Comment: Not quite duplicate but the answers might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8016296/479863

Comment: Actually I read that already, but the answer is quite obscure. I issued a new guestion because, that didn't focus directly into this guestion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Backbone-rails doesn't document `paramRoot`. I suppose you're supposed to use the generators to [build your models](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/backbone/model/templates/model.coffee):

```
class <%= model_namespace %> extends Backbone.Model
  paramRoot: '<%= singular_table_name %>'
  #...
```

and blindly do as you're told.

If you want to know what it does then you have to read the source (as usual). The only thing in Backbone-rails that uses `paramRoot` is their replacement for the standard [`Backbone.sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync); their replacement contains [this](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/backbone_rails_sync.js#L44):

```
if(model.paramRoot) {
  data[model.paramRoot] = model.toJSON();
} else {
  data = model.toJSON();
}
```

All that does is change a model's serialized attributes from the standard `{attr1: v1, attr2: v2, ...}` Backbone form to the `{ model_name: { attr1: v1, ... } }` form that Rails wants; then you can look at `params[:model_name]` in your Rails controllers rather than looking at just `params`.

Comment: A better solution might be to use [ActionController::ParamsWrapper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html).

Comment: @Maletor: That seems like a bit of hack to me (a different hack than the above hacks though :). Seems to be aimed at APIs that are in transition or backwards compatibility issues but I could be wrong about the intent. ParamsWrapper is worth mentioning though.