# Why is Backbone model sending duplicate attributes to server on save?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js, nested-attributes

I'm writing a practice Backbone app, with Rails backend API, and I'm confused about the behavior of save on Backbone models.

Let's say a Team has many Players, and I want to save a team with numerous players in a single POST.

So in Rails I have:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :players
end

class Player < ActiveRecod::Base
  belongs_to :team
end
```

and for backbone client, I have a Player model and a Players collection defined (not shown)

and then the containing Team model (NOTE: no Teams collection)

```
Demo.Models.Team = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/teams',
  defaults: {
    'team_size': 12
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.players = new Demo.Collections.Players());
  },
  toJSON: function() {
    var json = _.clone(this.attributes);
    json.players_attributes = this.players.map(function(player) {
      return player.toJSON();
    });
    return json;  
  }
}
```

When I examine my stringified JSON in the browser, everything looks good:

```
{"team_size":12, "players_attributes":[{"name":"Fred"},{"name":"Jim" },{"name":"Mark"}]}
```

Checking the server logs, the lone top level attribute ('team size') is repeated, once at the top level, and then repeated under a root key.

```
Started POST "/teams" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-07 13:39:40 -0400
Processing by TeamsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {
    "team_size"=>12, "players_attributes":[{"name":"Fred"},{"name":"Jim" },{"name":"Mark"}]}, 
    "team"=>{"team_size"=>12}
  }
```

I have a few questions:

1. What's the best way to ensure the player_attributes are nested inside the root key? I (So that I can do a nested save inside TeamController, in the standard rails manner: (i.e. Team.create(params[:team]) )  I can accomplish this with some javascript hackery inside toJSON, but I'm guessing there's an easier, cleaner way.
2. Is this standard, desirable behaviour? To send duplicates of attributes like this? I guess there's no harm, but it doesn't smell right.
3. Am I not defining the url / urlRoot correctly or some such?

thanks

Comment: Backbone sends exactly the result of toJSON(): `params.data = JSON.stringify(model.toJSON());`, so either your model contains such attributes or something strange on the server (there is waste closing brace in the log). Check the content of the http request in firebug to find out whom to blame.

Comment: I've had this same problem with Backbone and Rails for a while... now I need to optimize and this is becoming obnoxious... any idea where it's coming from?

Comment: I think it's worth noting that in my case (and probably yours, too), backbone appears to be sending non-duplicated information.  Firebug is telling me that the POST request sent to my server contained the correct, non-duplicated info.  However, somewhere before it turns in to the ruby "params", it duplicates some stuff... why?

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your problem but rails has a config to namespace all your JSON objects with the root node. This could be causing your issue. include_root_in_json = true if you set that to false you will no longer see team as your root node which is where your duplication is coming from. Rails is setting that for you. By default backbone doesn't like having a root node either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- You have to override the toJSON method in order to include the model name as the root of the JSON element sent to the server.

```
 toJSON: function() {
    return { team: _.clone( this.attributes ) }
  },
```

Since you are already messing and overriding this method I don't see any reasons not to go this way.

2- This is a very strange behavior you're describing. Try:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.include_root_in_json = false
end
```

It will probably eliminate Rails duplicate params parsing. Another advantage you get from this is that Rails won't include the team as a root element of its generated JSON to the client.

3- Your definition of urlRoot is just fine.

Comment: This appears to work as long as you don't patch. If you are using ```save``` with ```{patch: true}```, then the Backbone sync method prefers the attrs that were changed instead of calling the toJSON method.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here while looking for same issue. So even it's an old question I think it's worth giving the answer.

I actually found a Rails setting that explain these duplicate attributes: wrap_parameters

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionController/ParamsWrapper/ClassMethods/wrap_parameters

Just set it to an empty array, and rails won't try to wrap parameters coming from your JSON requests.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use the toJSON hack mentioned by others, this is actually not such a good idea. For one, it produces an inconsistent result between `sync` and `save` with `{patch: true}` (this inconsistency is because the sync method calls toJSON if you don't patch, but doesn't call toJSON if you have patch set to true)

Instead, a better solution is to use a patched version of Backbone that overload the sync method itself. The backbone-rails gem does this automatically, or you can pull backbone_rails_sync.js into your own app. A more complete answer to this question can be found here: [Backbone.js and Rails - How to handle params from Backbone models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272070/backbone-js-and-rails-how-to-handle-params-from-backbone-models?rq=1)